# Evaluating prefix expressions

Tags: c, abstract-syntax-tree

I have this long code for evaluating prefix evaluation. They give me a grammar for the prefix expressions which as the following `EXPR := OP EXPR EXPR | CONSTANT`, where `OP` is one of `+, -, *, /, %`.

All answers will be adapt to C's behavior to operators.

```c
typedef struct _TreeNode{
    long long int data;
    struct _TreeNode* left;
    struct _TreeNode* right;
}TreeNode;

TreeNode* head = NULL;

void constructTree(TreeNode** head){
    char in = getchar();
    char after = getchar();
    int flag=0;
    long long int val;
    if(isdigit(in)==1){
        ungetc(after, stdin);
        ungetc(in, stdin);
        scanf("%lld", &val);
        getchar();
        flag = 1;
    }
    if(*head==NULL){
        *head = (TreeNode*) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        
if(!flag) {(*head)->data = in; /*printf("input is in %d and isdigit =%d\n", in, isdigit((*head)->data));*/}
        else {(*head)->data = val; /*printf("input is val%d\n", val);*/}
        (*head)->right = (*head)->left = NULL;
        
if((*head)->left ==NULL && (*head)->data == '+'|| (*head)->data == '-' || (*head)->data == '*' || (*head)->data == '/' || (*head)->data == '%')
            constructTree(&(*head)->left);
        

if((*head)->right ==NULL && (*head)->data == '+'|| (*head)->data == '-' || (*head)->data == '*' || (*head)->data == '/' || (*head)->data == '%')
            constructTree(&(*head)->right);
    }
}
long long int eval(TreeNode* head){
    if(head->left!=NULL && head->right !=NULL){
        switch(head->data){
            case '*':
            return eval(head->left) * eval(head->right);
            break;

            case '/':
            return eval(head->left) / eval(head->right);
            break;

            case '+':
            return eval(head->left) + eval(head->right);
            break;

            case '-':
            return eval(head->left) - eval(head->right);
            break;

            case '%':
            return eval(head->left) % eval(head->right);
            break;
        }
    }
    return head->data;
}

void deleteTree(TreeNode* head){
    if(head!=NULL){
        deleteTree(head->left);
        deleteTree(head->right);
        free(head);
    }
}
```

I have tested this with my own test cases but seems like my online judge system won't accept it because there are wrong answers. any suggestions?
the sample input I got is this : `+ * 87 89 666` and I get my output `8409`, which is correct.

Inside the function `constructTree`, I also have changed the `if` condition to make child nodes into `if((*head)->left==NULL && !flag)` in the case of some integers input which have the same integer value for the ASCII characters, but this results in time limit error instead. (Note that the code above did not pass the time limit at all)

Answer (score 0):

I did not consider negative numbers.
If the input were: `+ * 87 89 -666`, I would read the `-666` as `-` instead.